# Istanbul test coverage report show that i'm covering only one file

Tags: mocha.js, istanbul

This is the first time that I'm using [Istanbul 2.0](https://istanbul.js.org/), but the reports shows that I'm covering only one file, and this file doesn't matter enough.

In my **package.json** I put the following settings

```
  "nyc": {
    "check-coverage": true,
    "include": [
      "src/**/*.js"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "src/config/*.js",
      "src/adapter/*.js"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm install && nodemon src/server",
    "test": "nyc --reporter=html mocha --recursive"
  }
```

**UPDATE**

When I change de package JSON puting the reporter in lcov, it works.

```
"test": "nyc --reporter=lcov mocha --recursive"
```

**VS Code**

[image]

**Istanbul HTML Report**

[image]